# Node.js script for editing a .xlsx file

Tags: node.js, csv, xlsx

I have a large .xlsx file where each row contains a person's name and various other information. Some rows have duplicate entries throughout the file. I'd like to create a Node.js script that parses the file and deletes the rows with duplicate entries. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xlsx

Comment: Nobody will write the complete code for you. Do some research and try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [Sheet.js](http://sheetjs.com/) to be the easiest way to interact with Excel files in node.  They publish the `xlsx` node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx.

The documentation can be a bit confusing, however.  If you have specific issues during your implementation, feel free to edit your question with code or ask a new question!

Concerning your specific scenario, the xlsx module comes with some nifty ways to convert spreadsheets to and from arrays of arrays as well as arrays of objects.  You say you have "a large .xlsx file". If it is truly massive, you might consider something like a stream read from the spreadsheet populating a new array with duplicates as you go.  Then, using the original spreadsheet, stream it again into a new document ommiting the entries from the duplicates array.

However the array-of-arrays helpers etc might be an easier route.  I have done in-memory processing of CSVs with nearly 100,000 rows (~50MB).  It's a bit slow, but definitely possible.

Hope that helps

https://docs.sheetjs.com