# Create excel file from data in csv file with node.js

Tags: node.js

I am developing MEAN stack application. I get data from a .csv file. Then I need to convert excel file and put the data from .csv file in excel file. This is achievable with multiple npm packages.

However the main problem is that I need to create pre defined excel file (I have excel template which I need to fill with the data)

How can I achieve that? I would be very happy if someone could suggest me some npm package or provide me with some documentation to achieve that with nodejs.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like this question was already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199580/18891587

Comment: But can I use some excel fiel as template and fill that file with data? Or it creates excel file from scratch? Because my file is very complex